# SQL Server - Agent Proxy Error "CryptUnprotectData failed (1325)"

Tags: sql-server-2005, administration

Job History:

```
Message
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Could not get proxy data for proxy_id = 4). The step failed.
```

---

Agent Log:

```
[442] CryptUnprotectData failed (1325).
```

Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3080.00 (X64) Sep 6 2009 09:15:46 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
product_level - SP2
edition - Standard Edition (64-bit)
```

---

I've done the setup following two different paths:

1. replication setup wizard manually,
2. specifically following these instructions:[how-to-run-sql-server-agent-and-sql-server-jobs-with-least-privilege-in-sql-server-2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/varun_sharma/how-to-run-sql-server-agent-and-sql-server-jobs-with-least-privilege-in-sql-server-2005)

---

SQL Agent and SQL Server both run under Local System accounts which are members of the local group, administrators

---

I don't see this kb article as applying:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938086

- not a high # of calls
- error messages aren't even close

---

The account being pointed to by the credentials is also an administrator on the box.

---

[SSIS Package not running under proxy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ca07755-0928-47d7-9e40-1aec0b24474d/ssis-package-not-running-under-proxy?forum=sqlintegrationservices) is not the case.

---

Of course, changing the job step to run under the sql agent account works fine.